# How can I display a custom attribute for upselling products?

Tags: magento-1.9, upselling

I want to add the following custom attribute to my upsell block:

[image]

So I tried

```
        <?php $_link->getBasePriceAmount(); ?>
```

and

```
        <?php $_link->getAttributeText('base_price_amount'); ?>
```

but both don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad I forgot "echo" :/ ... the first variety works for text fields

Comment: if you solved the problem, please mark the answer as accepted (as soon as you are allowed to).

Answer (score 1):

```
$_link->getResource()->getAttribute('base_price_amount')->getFrontend()->getValue($_link);
```

it is not work then you need to enable this attribute

```
used in product listing value to **Yes**
```

and try to get data by `<?php $_link->getBasePriceAmount(); ?>`